# Is it possible to find the mass of a planet and its moon from only their diameter and the distance between them?

Tags: newtonian-gravity, mass, orbital-motion, planets, celestial-mechanics

For example, a planet has a diameter of 200,000 km and its moon has a diameter of 20,000 km, the distance between them is 100,000 km. Would it be possible to find their masses?

Comment: I think you have to know more: 'Newton used his laws of motion and gravity to generalize Kepler's third law of planet orbits to cover any case where one object orbits another. He found for any two objects orbiting each other, the sum of their masses, planet mass + moon mass = (4p2/G) × [(their distance apart)3/(their orbital period around each other)2]. Newton's form of Kepler's third law can, therefore, be used to find the combined mass of the planet and the moon from measurements of the moon's orbital period and its distance from the planet. http://www.astronomynotes.com/solarsys/s2.htm

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate the sum of the masses from the period and the sem-major axis. This is a routine calculation easily Googled and the result is:

$$ m_a + m_b = \frac{4\pi^2r^3}{G\tau^2}  $$

If you can observe the system closely enough to locate the centre of mass and each star's distance from it then you can determine the individual masses.

You could also estimate the masses by assuming the densities are similar in which case the masses are proportional to the volumes. However if you can study the system closely enough to determine the radii you woul be able to determine the centre of mass and use that instead.